# Как найти координаты конца отрезка, зная координаты начала, длину отрезка и вектор направления?

Tags: математика, геометрия

На плоскости даны длина отрезка l, координаты начала отрезка [A, B], и координаты вектора направления [A1, B1]
По какой формуле можно найти координаты конца отрезка [X,Y] ?

Answer (score 3):

Нормируем вектор направления (если он не единичный)

```
norm = sqrt(a1^2+b1^2)
dx = a1 / norm
dy = b1 / norm
```

И рассчитываем точку на нужном удалении

```
endx = a + dx * l
endy = b + dy * l
```

Comment: @Сергей Бердник Знаете, что делать с полученными ответами?